# RabbitMQ tutorials code not working

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

I am in the process of learning RabbitMQ. I started with the basic rabbitmq tutorials in their website, unfortunately I am not able to compile them due to the following errors:

```
ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
factory.setHost("localhost");
```

**Error**: "The method newConnection(Address[]) in the type ConnectionFactory is not applicable for the arguments ()"

Connection connection = factory.newConnection();

**Error**: The method newConnection(Address[]) in the type ConnectionFactory is not applicable for the arguments ()

The maven dependency I have is:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.rabbitmq</groupId>
<artifactId>rabbitmq-client</artifactId>
<version>0.9.1</version>
</dependency>
```

What exactly am I doing wrong here? Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your tutorial seems to be "old", try out a more up to date version. [The current release of the RabbitMQ Java AMQP library is 3.1.3.](http://www.rabbitmq.com/java-client.html). But also have a look at the [Maven Repository](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.rabbitmq/amqp-client). Try out version 3.1.1, it's the newest version in the mvn repo.

```
<dependency> 
    <groupId>com.rabbitmq</groupId>
    <artifactId>amqp-client</artifactId> 
    <version>3.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```